# Python: list index out of range error

Tags: python, error-handling

I get this error on the line: `if line[0].startswith(element):`
I don't know why I am getting this error. Can anyone help. Thank you.

```
f = open ('testLC31.txt', 'r')
lineCount = 0

toIgnore = ["AND", "ADD", "LEA", "PUTS", "JSR", "LD", "JSRR" , "NOT", "LDI" ,
            "LDR", "ST", "STI", "STR", "BR" , "JMP", "TRAP" , "JMP", "RTI" ,
            "BR", "ST", "STI" , "STR" , "BRz", "BRn" , "HALT"]

label = []
instructions = []
i = 0

for line in f:
    line = line.split()

    for element in toIgnore:
        if line[0].startswith(element):
            lineCount += 1
        else:
            label.append(line[0])
            instructions.append(line[1])
            i += 1
            lineCount += 1
```

SAMPLE FILE:

```
.ORIG x3000

     AND    R0, R0, #0        
     AND    R1, R1, #0        
     AND    R2, R2, #0        
     AND    R7, R7, #0        

     LEA    R0, MSG1          
     PUTS                     

     LEA    R1, MEMORYSPACE   

     JSR    STRNG             

     LD     R0, NEWLINE
     OUT

     ADD    R0, R1, #0        
     LD     R2, NEG48         
     ADD    R0, R0, R2        
     PUTS                     

     HALT

     MSG1          .STRINGZ   "Input a string (length <= 9): "
     MEMORYSPACE   .BLKW      9
     NEWLINE       .FILL      #10
     NEG48         .FILl      #-48

          .END
```

Comment: Do you have any empty line in your file?

Comment: well first thing print line in your loop to see what it is

Comment: put an `if line.strip()` to catch empty lines and use `with`  to open your files or at least close them

Comment: i put a 
print (line) 
right before 
for element in toIgnore:  
and i get the correct results

Comment: @PadraicCunningham where would i put the if line.strip()  ?

Comment: can you add a sample file?

Comment: and you could try this `if line.strip and line[0].startswith(element):`

Comment: thanks @JohnRuddell I added my sample file

Comment: you have some issues with the code... so first thing... a line can just be \n which will not split returning an empty array. you also have other lines that have only one word and can only split once so line[1] will fail.

Comment: @JohnRuddell  yea but i am always getting line[0] so it should not update to line[1]

Comment: @Chalupa after fixing the line[0] error you reach another one... when you have the word PUTS by itself... line.split() works fine and its not the first item in the ignore list so it reaches the else when you append your instruction line[1] which doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few issues with this, I don't know what your requirement is so this is one approach.. but you are adding the exact same word for every instance that its not in the ignore list so there will be a LOT of duplicates. if you want that removed let me know and I can add that for you

```
for line in f:
    if line.split(): #check to see if it is actually something that can be split
        elem = line.split()
        if len(elem) > 1: #check to see that its more than one word if its not then you are on one of the ignore words
            for element in toIgnore:
                if elem[0].startswith(element):
                    lineCount += 1
                else:
                    label.append(elem[0])
                    instructions.append(elem[1])
                    i += 1
                    lineCount += 1
```

if you want to have unique instructions in your list then you can just do this

```
f = open ('testLC31.txt', 'r')
line_count = 0

to_ignore = ["AND", "ADD", "LEA", "PUTS", "JSR", "LD", "JSRR" , "NOT", "LDI" ,
            "LDR", "ST", "STI", "STR", "BR" , "JMP", "TRAP" , "JMP", "RTI" ,
            "BR", "ST", "STI" , "STR" , "BRz", "BRn" , "HALT"]

label = []
instructions = []
i = 0
for line in f:
    elem = line.split() if line.split() else ['']
    if len(elem) > 1 and elem[0] not in to_ignore:
        label.append(elem[0])
        instructions.append(elem[1])
        i += 1
        line_count += 1
    elif elem[0] in to_ignore:
        line_count += 1
```

Comment: i do want unique elements but that won't update lineCount for the lines that have words in them that are in toIgnore

Comment: @Chalupa see my edit for keeping a linecount when your element is in the ignore list. I also changed the variables/objects to use the accepted python object naming convention

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get an index out of range error is that `"".split()` results in an empty list `[]`. Thus when an empty line is read, it leads to an empty list `line`, and `list[0]` results in an out of range error.